# Node unexpectedly deletes all children nodes without having any code to do that

Tags: godot4

I build an app to manage recipes and a shopping list, and made a menue to look at and change the shopping list. When I load in the shopping list into the menue the first time it works without a problem, but when I change an amount or add something new to the shoppinglist(except when the shopping list is empty), it deletes all child nodes, so I have an empty control node. This seems to happen after the skript in the shoppinglist is actually done.
Project download: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12OlRoYzAFPxub3I5n3pq0k2bYWekQ6Ea/view?usp=sharing

To reproduce the bug you might need to create 1 or two ingredients.

I tried to narrow the bug down, and check with a printstatement if the nodes are gone or invisible, added a timer to check if they go invisible, but the timer also gets deleted, add a node after all children are deleted, tried googling the problem, read some documentation.

note:
The project was migrated from Godot 3 to godot 4